# how to animate dots in sequence

Tags: after-effects

I'm new to After Effects and wondering how that's possible to animate opening for this map so each dot appears individually? I know how to make the opening using the mask but it shows the edges while I'd like to have "popping one by one dots" animation.Please see image below:[image]

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial can help you:

You will find there how to make dotted effect from scratch (use outlines of the map). Then you shall add some key-frames for animation.

To make dots appear more random, you can use Fractal Noise as animated mask.

Good luck!

Comment: "how that's possible to animate opening for this map so ***each dot appears individually***?" Halftone effect does not give you control of "each dot" to make them "appear individually". It's a random effect.

Comment: "popping one by one dots" can be accomplished with Fractal Noise mask. Author did not say, that he need some special order for each dot. In that case, of course it shall be done manually.

Comment: You could create an animated gradient as the picture layer in the technique above to control when the dots popped on.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
http://misterhorse.tv/new-feature-stagger-layers/

Let's you randomize the order layers appear in.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up animating this map manually. The easiest way to me was to animate dots frame by frame in Flash and import movie to AE.